# Malformed Array Literal postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I would like to insert data in the form of a string in a column of type array (char[]) only my request returns the error "Malformed Array Literal"

here is my request:

```
async function insertTag(req, res) {
    return db.none('UPDATE user_account SET tag_property = $1 WHERE email = $2',
            [req.body.tag_id, req.body.email])
        .then(function () {
            res.status(200)
                .json({
                    status: 'success',
                    message: 'Updated user',
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
}
```

here is my data table [image]

```
tagIdInput: '',
InsertTagUserAccount(){
                fetch('http://192.168.1.51:3000/api/v1/tag_insertion', {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        email : 'monemail@gmail.com',
                        tag_id : '{' + this.tagIdInput + '}',
                    }),
                })
                // Converting to JSON
                .then(response => response.json())
                // Displaying results to console
                .then(json => console.log(json));       
                },
```

How can I fix that ?

Comment: I am confused. Is  `tag_id` an array? If yes, does it contain multiple IDs? A column defined as `char[]` doesn't really make sense to me. What exactly do you want to store there? A column storing a "string"  should be defined as `text` (or `varchar`) . If you want to de-normalize and store multiple IDs in a single column to make your life harder, then it should be `text[]` or probably `int[]` if those IDs are numbers

Comment: I want to be able to store several "names" that I call "tag_id" of this form 'tag_7z8eq87' so that on a row of my data table a person can have one or more "tag_id", text[] seems to me to be a better idea thanks ! I will put a photo of my data table in my question @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: My problem now is i don't now how to add a new tag_id instead of replacing the old one, example: from {tag_7z8eq87} -> {tag_7z8eq87, tag_7z8eq72} instead of {tag_7z8eq87} -> {tag_7z8eq72} @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Please show us the value of `req.body`. Does `.tag_id` contain a string with array literal syntax? Or an array of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't now how to add a new `tag_id` instead of replacing the old one

See [modifying arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-MODIFYING) in the docs and use the [`array_append` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) for that:

```
UPDATE user_account
SET tag_property = array_append(tag_property, $1)
WHERE email = $2;
```

If your frontend code is actually sending an array of multiple items to add, you can use

```
UPDATE user_account
SET tag_property = tag_property || $1::text[]
WHERE email = $2;
```